# C# class not responding

Tags: c#, class

I am making a program that calculates an employee's wages based on their hours and pay rate. However, when I try to use the method I created in another class:

```
public void GrossPay(int i)
    {
        double GrossPay = 0.0;
        GrossPay = Hours[i] * PayRate[i];
        Wages[i] = GrossPay;
    }
```

trying to use it in my main program:

```
public static void Payroll()
    {
        int employeeID = 0;
        int hours = 0;
        double payRate = 0.0;
        double wages = 0.0;
        Payroll payroll = new Payroll(employeeID, hours, payRate, wages);

        for (int i = 0; i < payroll.EmployeeID.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Employee ID: {0}", payroll.EmployeeID[i]);
            Console.WriteLine("How many hours does employee {0} work?", payroll.EmployeeID[i]);
            string h = Console.ReadLine();
            payroll.Hours[i] = Convert.ToInt32(h);
            Console.WriteLine("What is the hourly wage for employee {0}?");
            string w = Console.ReadLine();
            payroll.PayRate[i] = Convert.ToInt32(w);
            Console.WriteLine("Employee ID: {0} \nGross Pay: {1}", payroll.EmployeeID[i], payroll.Wages[i]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Gross Pay returns 0, no matter what. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never called the method that you've built; You should invoke it before you read from the `Wages` property.

```
// ...
payroll.PayRate[i] = Convert.ToInt32(w);
payroll.GrossPay(i);
Console.WriteLine("Employee ID: {0} \nGross Pay: {1}", payroll.EmployeeID[i], payroll.Wages[i]);
// ...
```

This will fix your problem, but I recommend that you give [object oriented paradigm](https://www.google.ca/webhp?ie=UTF-8#q=object+oriented+programming+in+c%23) a shot. I recommend that you create an `Employee` class, which will have properties such as `Id`, `PayRate`, `Hours` and a property `Wages` which may look like this:

```
public double Wages
{
    get
    {
        return PayRate * Hours;
    }
}
```

Then, `Payroll` class may hold a sequence of employees: `List<Employee> Employees;`